# How to achieve two separate list of lists from a single list of lists of tuple with list comprehension?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Say, I have a two 2D list like below:

```
[[('a', '1'), ('a', '12'), ('a', '3')], [('b', '21'), ('b', '31')], [ ('c', '11')]]
```

The output I want to achieve is:

```
Output_list=[['1','12','3'], ['21','31'], ['11']]
```

The main complexity here is I want to achieve the output through a single `list comprehension`.

One of my attempts was:

```
print [a for innerList in fin_list1 for a,b in innerList]
```

Output:

```
['1', '12', '3', '21', '31', '11']
```

But, as you can see, though I have successfully retrieve the second elements of each tuple, i failed to retain my inner list structure.

Comment: Why are you so interested in "a single list comprehension"?  The most natural way would involve two list comps.

Comment: I know how can achieve it in natural ways. I am just trying experiment with list comprehension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, let's assign the data:

```
>>> data = [
  [('a', '1'), ('a', '12'), ('a', '3')],
  [('b', '21'), ('b', '31')],
  [('c', '11')],
]
```

You can use `itemgetter` to create a function that gets one element from the tuple:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> first = itemgetter(0)
>>> second = itemgetter(1)
```

Now you can transform inner lists by using `map`:

```
>>> [map(first, row) for row in data]
[['a', 'a', 'a'], ['b', 'b'], ['c']]
>>> [map(second, row) for row in data]
[['1', '12', '3'], ['21', '31'], ['11']]
```

You could also create `first` and `second` without using `itemgetter`:

```
def first(xs):
    return xs[0]

def second(xs):
    return xs[1]
```

Answer (score 4):

We start with this:

```
>>> l = [[('a', '1'), ('a', '12'), ('a', '3')], [('b', '21'), ('b', '31')], [ ('c', '11')]]
```

Initially you tried to do something along these lines:

```
>>> [y for sublist in l for x, y in sublist]
['1', '12', '3', '21', '31', '11']
```

The mistake here is that this list comprehension is one-dimensional, i.e. all the values will be just integers instead of lists themselves

In order to make this two-dimensional, our values need to be lists. The easiest way to do this is by having our value expression be a *nested* list comprehension that iterates over the elements of the sublists of the original list:

```
>>> [[y for x, y in sublist] for sublist in l]
[['1', '12', '3'], ['21', '31'], ['11']]
```

Technically this is two list comprehensions, but obviously a list comprehension can be replaced by `map` as explained in Roberto's answer.

Comment: I realized my mistake even before posting the question. This point is I didn't really think of a 2D list comprehension, thanks for nicely explaining it. I added those line just because I had to add an attempt with the question. +1.

Answer (score 1):

```
the_list = [[('a', '1'), ('a', '12'), ('a', '3')], [('b', '21'), ('b', '31')], [ ('c', '11')]]

new_list = [[x[1] for x in y] for y in the_list]

print new_list
```

Output:

> [['1', '12', '3'], ['21', '31'], ['11']]